# Not able to run WCF https web service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have created a `WCF HTTP` self hosted web service. Now i want to convert it into `HTTPS`. So i followed the following points:

Followed [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791%28VS.100%29.aspx) page to create a `certificates` and bind it to a specific port.
I create a certificate using `mmc`-> `console root` and followed the same steps written in above link.

Then i run following command to bind the port with certificate:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000 certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}
```

I change `certhash` according to my certificates. I also checked `Created certificate info` and got this.

[image]

I am also pasting the code written in my project to run web service on binded port:

```
try
  {
    m_running = true;
    private static String m_baseAddress = "https://10.0.0.1:8083";
    WebHttpBinding _binding = new WebHttpBinding();
    _binding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
    _binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
    m_serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(TService), new Uri(m_serviceAddress));
 m_serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,"contoso.com");
    ServiceEndpoint ep = m_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TContract), _binding, "");
     m_serviceHost.Open();
    }
     catch(Exception e){ }
```

Whenever i rebuild my project and run it. It always start for a second and get stopped. I check the log and nothing was present.

But when i removed this line

```
m_serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,"contoso.com");
```

and replace `https` to `http`. It works fine.

Comment: You're still using FindBySubjectName with "contoso.com" as the subject name. Is that the name used in your certificate?

Comment: In your m_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint() you are adding an new WebHttpBinding() without security mode configured. You should probably use the 'binding' that you have created before. But still I am surprised that you do not see any errors on starting. Also if you continue to see issues, try adding tracing and see if you get more information in that.

Comment: @MortenMertner From where i can see my certificate name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the following steps to create a `HTTPS` `WCF self hosted` web service.

- First, use netsh to add a namespace for reservation for the port:
    `netsh http add urlacl url=https://127.0.0.1+:8085/ user=EVERYONE`
- Type the following command to create a client certificate:
     `makecert -sk RootCA -sky signature -pe -n CN=localhost -r -sr  LocalMachine -ss Root MyCA.cer`
- Now create a server certificate:
  `makecert -sk server -sky exchange -pe -n CN=localhost -ir LocalMachine -is Root -ic MyCA.cer -sr LocalMachine -ss My MyAdHocTestCert.cer`

Two new `certificate` files are now created in `\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin` with the name of `MyCA.cer` and `MyAdHocTestCert.cer`

Open `server certificate` i.e. `MyAdHocTestCert.cer` and choose `thumbprint` from `details` tab.

[image]

- Select `thumbprint` and remove all of the spaces from it.
- Now bind the port with this certificate with the following command:
  `netsh http add sslcert ipport=127.0.0.1:8085 certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF} clientcertnegotiation=enable`

where

- `ipport :`  host address and port : put the same address as you choose in first step
- `certhash :`  thumbprint

Now you are done with certificate and port binding. To check everything write `netsh http show sslcert` in cmd and you got something like this:

[image: This is just an exaple]

Now write the following code for `WSHTTPbinding`:

```
WebHttpBinding _binding = new WebHttpBinding();
_binding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
_binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
m_serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Serviceclass), new Uri("https://127.0.0.1:8085/"));
             m_serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "611fe7748c5883f8082351744604a8c917608290");
            ServiceEndpoint ep = m_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(InstanceClass), _binding, "hello");
            m_serviceHost.Open();
```

Now create your consumer to use this self-hosted WS

Comment: It is the whole procedure to create self-hosted web service with SSL. the mistake I made was that I was creating the certificate from the wrong point